# Weird behavior while looping big list of words

Tags: python

1. When `#validCandidateList += word` stays commented, program runs fine. When this line is uncommented, program starts printing out some repeated line over and over again.
2. <s>2. As you can see `sorted(set(eWord))` is sorted, so for
   example if I input "dog", or "good", it creates same sorted list of
   letters - `['d', 'g', 'o']`, but the program does not print the
   out the word `good` when input is `dog`, even though you can
   confirm that both words exist in the dictionary, by inputting them
   in a single run of program, separated by spaces, or inputting one of
   the words in different program runs.</s>I am sorry, I just had to apply .lowercase() to the word. Dictionary contains some uppercase letters too.

   Please help.

```
import os

cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
fname = "\\dictionary.txt"
file = open(cwd + fname, "r")
readFile = file.read()
dictionary = readFile.split() #list type variable with more than 400 000 words.

input = input("Input your list of words, separated by spaces: ")
inputList = input.split()

validCandidateList = inputList

for eWord in dictionary: 
    for word in inputList:
        if sorted(set(eWord)) == sorted(set(word)):
            print(word, ": ",eWord)
            #validCandidateList += word

print(validCandidateList)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it!

Your line here:

```
validCandidateList = inputList
```

Does not copy the contents of `inputList` into a new variable named `validCandidateList` as you expect, it just links the two variables, so when you change `validCandidateList` inside your loop, it also changes `inputList` as well, which you are trying to loop over.  Changing the list you are looping over causes big issues in Python (don't do it).  So to fix this, you need to actually copy the contents of `inputList` into `validCandidateList` like this:

```
validCandidateList = inputList[:]
```

Alternatively you can use the `copy()` function if you're using Python 3

```
validCandidateList = inputList.copy()
```

This looks a bit more obvious for what you're doing, but either are perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 0):

As for the first problem you mentioned:

these lines are the origin of it:

```py
inputList = input.split()
validCandidateList = inputList
```

this is a reference assignment, that means whenever `validCandidateList` changes, `inputList` will change too.

you loop over `inputList` and inside the loop you change `validCandidateList`, which basically extends the loop, and you see the repeated output.

Example:

```py
x = [1,2,3]
y = x
y.append(4)
print(x)
# output => [1,2,3,4]
```

in order to correct that behavior, you can use the `copy` operator:

```py
validCandidateList = inputList.copy()
```

this makes a shallow copy of your list and make a new reference.

More info on how `copy` works can be found in the official docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to initialise your list with an empty list, rather than adding to the existing list, try this:

```py
validCandidateList = []
```

Then later on

```py
validCandidateList.append(word)
```

Hope this helps!